# „Sprechein oder ausgabe”

Tags: noun, compound, capitalization, hyphen, ellipsis

Angenommen, man möchte „Sprecheingabe oder Sprechausgabe“ zu „Sprechein oder ausgabe“ abkürzen. Wohin setzt man in „Sprechein oder ausgabe“ die Bindestriche und welche Buchstaben schreibt man darin groß und welche klein? Und warum?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Diese Fragestellung behandelt der [§98 des amtlichen Regelwerks](https://grammis.ids-mannheim.de/rechtschreibung/6209#). Er lautet:

> **Mit dem Ergänzungsstrich zeigt man an, dass in Zusammensetzungen oder Ableitungen einer Aufzählung ein gleicher Bestandteil ausgelassen wurde, der sinngemäß zu ergänzen ist.**
>
> [...]
> Dies betrifft
> [...]
> (3) den letzten und den ersten Bestandteil:
> *Textilgroß- und -einzelhandel (= Textilgroßhandel und Textileinzelhandel), Eisenbahnunter- und -überführungen*
> *Werkzeugmaschinen-Import- und -Exportgeschäfte*

Da du im ersten Wort (Sprecheingabe) den letzten Bestandteil (nämlich *-gabe*) weglässt und im zweiten Wort (Sprechausgabe) den ersten (*Sprech-*), trifft der hier wiedergegebene Absatz (3) zu, und daher ist das hier richtig:

> Sprechein- und -ausgabe

Dass das erste Wort groß zu schrieben ist sollte klar sein, denn es ist ein Substantiv (bzw. der Beginn eines unvollständigen Substantivs). Das zweite Wort wird nach dem Ergänzungsstrich klein weitergeschrieben, weil der großzuschreibende Anfang durch den Ergänzungsstrich ersetzt wurde und der ersetzte Bestandteil ja schon im ersten Wort sichtbar ist, und damit klar ist, dass auch das zweite Wort, sobald man es vervollständigt, ein Substantiv ist.

---

**Nicht mehr Teil der Antwort, aber zu lange für einen Kommentar:**

Ich möchte auch auf jene Kommentare bei der Frage und bei einer anderen Antwort eingehen, wo behauptet wurde, es gäbe das Wort *»Sprecheingabe«* nicht:

- [iPhone- oder iPad-Texte kann man auch über die **Sprecheingabe** diktieren.](https://www.pcwelt.de/tipps/iPhone-iPad-Texte-bequem-diktieren-statt-muehsam-eintippen-3544391.html)
- [Die **Sprecheingabe** von Win10 dagegen ist erbärmlich und kaum verwendbar](https://forum.chip.de/discussion/1897381/google-spracherkennung-in-windows-verwenden)
- [Das kann per **Sprecheingabe** oder ganz klassisch mit Tastatur und Maus erledigt werden.](https://www.win-10-forum.de/threads/windows-10-erinnerungen-ueber-cortana-einrichten-so-geht-es.3514/)
- [Und noch rätselhafter wird die Angelegenheit, wenn man die menschlichen Zwischenstationen auschaltet und in ein **Sprecheingabe**-Druckausgabe-Gerät spricht.](https://books.google.at/books?id=i3KgBgAAQBAJ&pg=PA19&lpg=PA19&dq=%22Sprecheingabe%22&source=bl&ots=7eJ7Ezn7vH&sig=ACfU3U2dtPn_lDSGVtj3LWiaNTMG3UeCzQ&hl=de&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiuvr63yuX1AhUDwAIHHR-tDKwQ6AF6BAgYEAM#v=onepage&q=%22Sprecheingabe%22&f=false) (Der Satz beginnt ungefähr in der Mitte des zweiten Absatzes)
- [Eine **Sprecheingabe** wird per Tipp aufs Mikro aktiviert, anschließend wird gesprochener Text erkannt und übersetzt.](https://macnotes.de/2011/02/09/google-translate-iphone-app-praktisch-gratis-nun-im-app-store/)
- [Haushaltsgeräte wie z.B. Küchengeräte, das Radio oder auch die Beleuchtung können bequem via **Sprecheingabe** bedient werden.](https://www.axxessio.com/de/news-de/mit-data-augmentation-zur-datenvielfalt)
- [NEU! von >Becker< Navigation mit **Sprecheingabe** ...und es funktioniert!](http://www.brenca.ch/Alarmanlagen/alarmanlagen.html)
- [Die Steuereinheit ist konfiguriert zum Durchführen einer Steuerung zum Identifizieren der Sprache einer durch die Sprechempfangseinheit empfangenen **Sprecheingabe**.](https://www.freepatentsonline.com/DE102019124350A1.html)
- [Tippen Sie auf diese Option *[Icon],* um weitere Funktionen des TouchPal zu öffnen, **Sprecheingabe**,Textbearbeitung, Tastaturmotive ändern und mehr.](https://www.manualslib.de/manual/118124/Zte-Blade-V8.html?page=45)

Und hier sind Belegstellen für die Sprechausgabe:

- [**Sprechausgabe** (Sonderzubehör) - Kenwood TS-2000 Bedienungsanleitung](https://www.manualslib.de/manual/653931/Kenwood-Ts-2000.html?page=101)
- [**Sprechausgabe** der Anrufnummer auf einem Google Home Mini](https://forum.fhem.de/index.php?topic=107281.0)
- [Was sind Ausgabegeräte? - Bildschirme, Drucker, **Sprechausgabe**, Lautsprecher](https://www.karteikarte.com/card/2379719/was-sind-ausgabegeraete)
- [Ich habe mir den neuen BMW Navigator4 einbauen lassen, jedoch hat dieser keine **Sprechausgabe** über meine Bähr-Helmsprechanlage (Kabel).](https://www.gs-forum.eu/threads/navigator4-keine-kommunikation-mit-sprechanlage-baehr-kabel.38714/)
- [Ich kann mit dem I-Drive auch mit dem Telefon anrufen, nur ob ich dann auch eine **Sprechausgabe** über die Lautsprecher erhalte ist ein Glücksspiel.](https://www.bmw-syndikat.de/bmwsyndikatforum/topic89101_W810i_und_Bluetooth_Freisprecheinrichtung_im_E60_Car_Hifi___Multimedia___Navigation.html)
- [**Sprechausgabe** durch den Lautsprecher](https://www.neue-haustuer.de/wp-content/uploads/2020/02/Kompo_Doorbird_Information.pdf)

Ich habe mich inzwischen zwar an die Wörter *»Spracheingabe«* und *»Sprachausgabe«* gewöhnt, aber natürlicher erscheinen mir nach wie vor die Begriffe *»Sprecheingabe«* und *»Sprechausgabe«,* weil hier keine Sprache (Deutsch, Englisch, Russisch usw.) ein oder ausgegeben wird, sondern das, was man beim Akt des Sprechens von sich gibt. Also:

- Spracheingabe: Wenn ich eingeben kann, in welcher Sprache mir z.B. eine Website angezeigt wird.
- Sprecheingabe: Wenn ich sprechen soll, um etwas einzugeben.

Mir ist aber selbstverständlich klar, dass das die Mehrheit offenbar anderes sieht, und ich verwende auch selbst ohne weiter darüber nachzudenken nicht das Wort *Sprecheingabe* sondern *Spracheingabe* wenn ich meine, dass man sprechen muss um etwas einzugeben, auch wenn  es mir mitunter noch immer seltsam vorkommt.

Dasselbe gilt für Sprachausgabe und Sprechausgabe: Wenn das Gerät zu mir spricht, würde ich eigentlich lieber *Sprechausgabe* sagen. Von einer *Sprachausgabe* würde ich nur reden, wenn mir ein Gerät sagt, in welcher Sprache ein Text vorliegt. Aber auch hier weiß ich natürlich, dass diese Ansicht eine Minderheitenmeinung ist.

Comment: Selbstverständlich existieren die Wörter *Sprecheingabe* und *Sprechausgabe* - spätestens, seit sie hier stehen. Ob sie deswegen **gebräuchlich** (mMn eher nicht, auch ngrams findet keine Belege) und **verständlich** (mMn eher schon) sind, und ob es empfehlenswert wäre, sie statt den wesentlich gebräuchlicheren **Sprachein- und -ausgabe** zu verwenden, wäre eine andere Frage. Dein Argument, das "Sprech-" besser passt, weil "Sprach-" sich auf *Language* bezieht, kann ich nicht nachvollziehen - Schließlich ist Sprache (auch) alles, was mit sprechen (Sprachorgane, Sprachzentrm,...) zu tun hat.

Comment: @tofro Die Wörter gibt's, werden gebraucht und verstanden. Dieser Thread ist nicht dafür da, die Häufigkeiten der Wörter zu diskutieren

Answer (score -2):

So:

Spracheingabe

Sprachausgabe

Mögliche Trennstriche:

Sprach-
ein-
gabe

Sprach-
aus-
gabe

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/133837/discussion-on-answer-by-stefan-pertschi-sprechein-oder-ausgabe).